# Let $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be a fully faithful covariant functor. Then, if $F(f):F(A_1)\to F(A_2)$ is an isomorphism, so is $f:A_1\to A_2$.

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, functors, morphism

I’d like to ask for checking of my attempt below.

> We want to find $g: A_2 \to A_1$ such that $f \circ g = 1_{A_2}$ and $g \circ f = 1_{A_1}$. So define $g: A_2 \to A_1$ to be a morphism such that $F(g \circ f) = 1_{F(A_1)}$.
>
> We first look at $(g \circ f)$. Let $h_1: A_1 \to A_2$ be an arbitrary morphism. First we want to show that $h_1 \circ (g \circ f) = h_1$.
> Now:
> \begin{align} F(h_1 \circ (g \circ f)) 
> &= F(h_1) \circ F(g \circ f) \ \ \ \text{(since $F$ is covariant)} \\
> &= F(h_1) \circ 1_{F(A_1)} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(by definition of $g$)} \\
> &= F(h_1)
> \end{align}
> Then, since $F$ is injective: $h_1 \circ (g \circ f) = h_1$.
>
> Similarly, we can let $h_2: A_2 \to A_1$ be an arbitrary morphism, and show that $(g \circ f) \circ h_2 = h_2$.
>
> The above shows that $g \circ f = 1_{A_1}$.

> To carry out the analysis for $(f \circ g)$ in a similar fashion, I’d need the fact that $F(f \circ g) = 1_{F(A_2)}$. I show it as follows:
>
> Since $F(f): F(A_1) \to F(A_2)$ is an isomorphism, there exists $F’: F(A_2) \to F(A_1)$ such that $F(f) \circ F’ = 1_{F(A_2)}$ and $F’ \circ F(f) = 1_{F(A_1)}$.
>
> Now from the definition of $g$, we have:
> \begin{align} 
> & \ \ \ F(g \circ f) = 1_{F(A_1)} = F’ \circ F(f) \\
> & \Rightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ F(g) \circ F(f) = F’ \circ F(f) \\
> & \Rightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ F(g) = F’
> \end{align}
> Then: $$F(f \circ g) = F(f) \circ F(g) = F(f) \circ F’ = 1_{F(A_2)}$$

I have several questions:

$1. $ Where is the assumption that $F$ is surjective used? I’m tempted to think that it enables $g$ to be defined the way it is: since $1_{F(A_1)} \in \text{Hom}(F(A_1),F(A_1))$, and $F$ is surjective, there exists $\varphi \in \text{Hom}(A_1,A_1)$ such that $F(\varphi) = 1_{F(A_1)}$. So $\varphi$ justifies the existence of $(g \circ f)$. I’d appreciate if other instances like that, if any, could be pointed out in my proof.

$2. $ I’m also asked to show that the injectivity of $F$ alone does not suffice. Is the above a good explanation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F(f):F(A_1)\to F(A_2)$ is an isomorphism, then this means there is $g':F(A_2)\to F(A_1)$ such that $g'\circ F(f)=1_{F(A_1)}$ and $F(f)\circ g'=1_{F(A_2)}$. Since $F$ is full, there is $g:A_2\to A_1$ with $F(g)=g'$. Now
$$F(g\circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)=g'\circ F(f)=1_{F(A_1)}$$
But also $F(1_{A_1})=1_{F(A_1)}$, so we must have $g\circ f=1_{A_1}$ since $F$ is faithful. A similar argument shows that $f\circ g=1_{A_2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When writing my proof, I had a suspicion that the fullness of $F$ could be used that way, but I was not sure. Specifically, I follow the definition that $F$ induces a function $F_{A_1,A_2}: \text{Hom}_\mathcal{A}(A_1,A_2) \to \text{Hom}_\mathcal{B}(F(A_1),F(A_2))$, and $F$ being full means that $F_{A_1,A_2}$ is surjective, i.e. for all $r \in \text{Hom}_\mathcal{B}(F(A_1),F(A_2))$, there exists $s \in \text{Hom}_\mathcal{A}(A_1,A_2)$ such that $F_{A_1,A_2}(s) = r$. But it seems you were using surjectivity in the other direction?

Comment: In your notation, I'm using surjectivity of $F_{A_2,A_1}$ with $r=g'$ and $s=g$.